# Is there a way to use non-utf 8 characters in StringStream?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, stringstream

I am scanning some of the files in the hard drive and I am putting them to DB with that simple code below.

```
            std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "INSERT INTO `test`.`file` ( `name`, `directory`, `size`, `extension`, `read_permission`, `write_permission`,`execute_permission`, `c_time`,`a_time`,`m_time`) VALUES ("<< "'"
            << app.e.name << "', " << "'"
            << app.e.directory << "', " << "'" << app.e.size << "', " << "'" << app.e.extension << "', " << "'"
            << app.e.read_permission << "', " << "'" << app.e.write_permission << "', " << "'" << app.e.execute_permission << "', " << "'" 
            << app.e.creation_time << "', " << "'" << app.e.execution_time << "', " << "'" << app.e.modification_time << "'); ";
```

However, some of the files in my hard drive contains non-utf 8 characters like

> [ 'Ö', 'Ç', 'Ş', 'ı', 'Ğ']

and it throws that exception:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x60a9d540 (msvcr100d.dll) in
>   DigitalForensicsVisualisation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   reading location 0x00000000."

Is there a way to store those characters in a stringstream?
 Or any other alternative data structures to stringstream which are allowing multiple concatenation in a line.

Comment: Fix the encoding of your strings so they are UTF-8.

Comment: `stringstream` doesn't care about character encodings. It happily accepts any raw bytes you feed it, even `\0`. Your bug lies somewhere else.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by non-UTF8 character, and why you think the posted fragment has anything to do with the crash. Windows filenames are not in UTF-8 anyway. They are UTF-16 and Windows compilers work natively in UTF-16 with wchar_t. Either use "w" C++ strings throughout, or explicitly convert from wchar_t/utf16 to char/utf8 on input, and back for output.

Comment: Oh, and somewhat off topic: Learn about SQL-injection attacks and little Bobby Tables. And then you print out and burn that piece of code :)

Comment: At least use a naming convention to mark which variables are safe to use in SQL (i.e. they've had their special characters escaped). Also check that the encoding on your database matches the encoding in your SQL. (E.g. MySQL likes to default to `latin1` instead of `utf8`).

Comment: There is not enough code here to guess the answer, and most likely the problem is somewhere else entirely. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: 1. UTF-8 holds all symbols supported my Unicode standard. There is no any difference between UTF-8, UTF-16 (LE/BE) and UTF-32 (LE/BE) in terms of Unicode standard support.
2. std::stringstream has notthing to deal with UTF or any other encoding. std::stringstream is raw byte stream.
3. Your question is about locale which looks like default "C" locale and not any UTF one.